# Can you store a generic dictionary in Properties.Settings in 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, application-settings, settings.settings

The new `Dictionary<Tkey,TValue>` in .net 4.0 is serializable, so... can I now somehow use this in the `Settings.Settings` or `Settings.Designer.cs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of.  You can define a non-generic class that inherits from the generic class and then reference it in your settings.  For example:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClassDictionary : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, MyClass>
    {}
}
```

Your namespace may not appear in the list of assemblies/namespaces when you select "browse" for your setting's type, but you can just enter the fully qualified name of the type (e.g., `MyNamespace.MyClassDictionary`) into the text box at the bottom of the dialog.  You will need to compile once after defining your custom collection.